# Way to fix csv data and insert columns at a specific spot for specific rows

Tags: python, excel, csv

Okay, so I have this excel sheet and a csv with a bunch of data, then whoever made it put in an item description deliminated by '*'. I can have excel or use python to separate this into different columns, but for some reason, the people who made the excel sheet did not have the same columns for all the data in that monstrous item description. It makes it where if the type of item starts with a particular description, it has an ID column with a number, and a column that just says ID, but for all the other items, there is no ID column or the "ID" in the other column. So those materials are shifted two columns to the left. Do you know of a way to fix this using python and or excel without manually going through and adding things? I am trying to figure out a way to use an if statement to loop through that row in the csv and add an ID=0 and "ID" columns in the right place for those rows, but I cannot figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Please could you use an example of some of the data? It'll be easier to visualise